# Export Archive with Xcode13: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

### Xcode 13.2.1 Exporting Archive for Development team with "Distribute App" fails

##### Xcode 13.1 - works on the same MacBook to export IPA for development distribution. No errors!!

##### Xcode13.2.1 "Validate App" is successful, Error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." occurs only with the distribution.

[image: dev-export]
[image: distribute-validate]

Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

From the standard log:

```
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  /Users/dev.d/.gem/ruby/2.6.3/gems/CFPropertyList-3.0.3/lib/cfpropertylist/rbCFPropertyList.rb:83: warning: assigned but unused variable - temp
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  Ignoring ffi-1.14.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  Ignoring json-2.5.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.5.1
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  Ignoring json-1.8.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.6
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  Ignoring nokogiri-1.10.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.10.3
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:24:in `<main>'
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool exited with 1
2022-02-16 00:42:46 +0000  ipatool JSON: (null)
```

Comment: Have you got solution for this? I am facing issue while exporting development archive.

Comment: Could this link help? It seems to give some clues but I haven't got it working yet either— https://www.egeek.me/2018/04/14/ipa-export-error-in-xcode-and-ruby/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Xcode folder > right click open Get Info > make sure open using Rosetta has been checked

don't forget quit Xcode then open it

[image: settings]

Comment: This works just fine! Is this the issue on Xcode side?

Comment: I have this problem on device but it is ok on simulator @Ala'a Abu Nemeh

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got the error only when I open Xcode with the capacitor cli (`npx cap open ios`). I can create a distribution by opening Xcode with Spotlight.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but for me it was because I forgot to change the bundle identifier when I deployed my app on an Iphone. In my case, it was due to signing.

If thats also the case for you, I think you can try something like this :

- click your project root in the project explorer, then in the editor go to "Signing and capabilities".
- change your bundle identifier to something different, e.g. something like com.test.username.appname

Another thing you can try if things like that happen is :

- if you are using automatically manage signing, untick it and then tick it again, it will process everything again.

I hope this will help you with your issue.

Comment: I did all of this with no luck, but after restarting my mac the issue disappeared.

Comment: Alright ! Glad it worked for you, even if I didnt help much in the end

Comment: This is not working

Comment: I can't tell exactly whether or not those steps did help but I made those before restarting my machine, so probably the sum of both steps did solve the issue in some way in case, so thank you @0ozen!

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to open your xCode without rosetta this solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

In my case Distribute development certificate was expired!
So I created another one and then restarted the XCode.
That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced this issue using M1 chip.

Following steps resolved the issue:

- Check if Xcode is open using Rosetta or not.
- Just toggle (if checked then uncheck/if unchecked then check it) the open using Rosetta.
- Open your Xcode and distribute the app.

Then you will be able to upload your archive.

Answer (score 0):

i was using console to open xcode, instead of that when i opened xcode from finder the issue got resolved.